# Weld-osgi-bundle-2.2.10.Final unable to resolve sun.misc

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, weld

I am trying to install weld-osgi-bundle to apache felix and I get this exception -

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle [15]: Unable to resolve 15.0: missing requirement [15.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=sun.misc)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4097)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2114)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:977)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:964)
```

The only way I know is to put this in Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES of Felix config as JDK provides this package. Something like this:

```
String SYSTEM_PACKAGES = "sun.misc";
configMap.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES, SYSTEM_PACKAGES);
```

However, if I follow this way I will have to export all used `javax` etc packages. How to solve such problem? I tried to find `osgi` bundle with sun.misc but couldn't.

Comment: Hmm, strange, this dependency wasn't there in version 2.2.9.Final and I think it should be avoided. Could you file an issue?

Comment: @Puce Hi! Open this bundle and see manifest file. There you can find this dependency.

Comment: Yes, that's how I checked it wasn't there in version 2.2.9.Final. So it must be something new with version 2.2.10.Final - hopefully a mistake that can be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES` with `FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA`. This appends to the system package exports, rather than overwriting them.